# MSSQL Server 2019 SSIS installation

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2019

Currently our DBA team is tasked with supporting SSIS however we would like to separate the SSIS service from the actual database engine. The reason is to be able to have different teams responsible for updates and maintenance of other 3rd party applications on the SSIS server. We would like the DBA team to handle the database engine updates or maintenance . This will allow the SSIS team to do there updates to there apps and not need access Database engine server.

A few years ago a similar question was aked about having SSIS packages on one server while having the database packages from the last comment looks like it maybe possible but not sure how it would be executed.

[SSIS Installation on Dedicated Server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/222185/ssis-installation-on-dedicated-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little unclear what you're trying to accomplish, or the "*why*" you're trying to accomplish this. "The reason is to be able to have different teams responsible for updates and maintenance of other 3rd party applications on the SSIS server." - This is vague, by 3rd party applications, do you mean database applications, SSIS packages, or actual non-database software running on the server?

"*...we would like to separate the SSIS service from the actual database engine*" - SSIS is a feature that coexists to the main SQL Server instance and engine, but is already separated as it's own running service. If you wanted to just use the SSIS service on a separate server, you'd have to install a second SQL Server instance (which means paying additional licensing for it as well). SSIS makes use of it's own database [`SSISDB`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/catalog/ssis-catalog?view=sql-server-ver15) for storing a multitude of things including parameters and runtime history. So the main service for the SQL instance which is inclusive of the engine has to exist for SSIS packages to be able to execute and function properly.

If you want division of responsibilities and access use proper security provisioning such that your SSIS team has access to only the functions they need with SSIS on your database server.